# The calculated series of $T(n)$ is: $T(n)= \{1,3,6,10,15,21,28,36,45,55,66\}$ for $n=0$ to $n=10$, how do you write this using sigma notation?

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

The calculated series of $T(n)$ is: $T(n)= \{1,3,6,10,15,21,28,36,45,55,66\}$ for $n=0$ to $n=10$, how do you write this using sigma notation?
$T(n)$ contains the functions:

- $T(n−1) + (n+1)$ for $n\geq1$
- $T(0) = 1$

Comment: You mean something like this: $$T(n)=\sum_{k=1}^{\frac{(n+1)(n+2)}{2}}\,1\,?$$  I used *sigma notation* as requested.

Comment: These are triangular numbers. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_number answers your question immediately.

Comment: for Batominovski, how was this arranged? "k=1" is the intial instance, so  "((n+1)(n+2))/2" is the nth sequence? What is 1 for? These are indeed triangular numbers but i'm having a hard time understanding what sigma formula would be used for each instance of n from 0 to the nth number since the sequence is not a simple arithmetic or geometric format.

Comment: I hope you realize @Batominovski was being a bit facetious.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So we have

\begin{align}
T(0)&=1\\
T(1)&=3\\
T(2)&=6\\
T(3)&=10\\
T(4)&=15\\
T(5)&=21\\
T(6)&=28\\
T(7)&=36\\
T(8)&=45\\
T(9)&=55\\
T(10)&=66\\
\end{align}
So it appears that
$$ T(n)=\sum_{k=0}^n(k+1) $$

Comment: Thank you! that makes a lot of sense! and I found out k is better for sigma than doing multiple n notations.

Answer (score 1):

Not to be a smart-arse but the following is another solution:

\begin{equation}
 S = \sum_{t \in T(n)} t
\end{equation}